# Help me choose a good chinese name

Tags: simplified-characters, traditional-characters, names, literary-chinese

I'm currently learning chinese and I've decided to adopt a chinese name since my given name doesn't translates well to mandarin. I wanted to choose a nome that comes from ancient poetry and evoques beauty/elegance, as well as a good character.

I liked the name 雪盈 from this verse by poet Xin Qiji: "蛾儿雪柳黄金缕，笑语盈盈暗香去". I was thinking about 馮 or 方 as the surname since they kind of remind me of my original surname.

Is this a good name, or does it sound weird, funny, or wrong in any aspect for native speakers? If so, could you give some suggestions on finding a more appropriate one?

Comment: may i ask, what's your mother tongue?

Comment: Brazilian portuguese

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This is not an answer per se, but definitely too long to be in the comments)

Don't get me wrong, both 馮雪盈 and 方雪盈 sound very nice to me. The *ci* is equally aesthetic. However, in this *ci*, it is often said that Xin Qiji had a deeper overtone than to merely describe the many sightings (people included, as in your quoted verse) of the Lantern festival. His pursuit of 'that person' 那人 standing well away from the crowds in the last verse is *said to be* a reflection of his patriotism (to Northern Song), which, at that time (Southern Song), is sadly largely forgotten by his contemporaries who found complacency in this kind of life. In a way, he was *contrasting* his motive with these very glamorous descriptions of the festival.

In light of this, it would be perfect if 雪 and 盈 are found in other sources of poetry that provide a better justification (without the historical connotations above). Perhaps the *Book of Odes* or other *ci* works. I leave that for others who are more familiar with poetry to answer. However, do keep in mind sometimes 雪 itself (not as part of a compound word like 雪柳) may confer a different, perhaps lonely imagery, such as [江雪](https://eastasiastudent.net/china/classical/liu-zongyuan-jiang-xue/). I only felt obliged to inform you the way this *ci* can potentially be interpreted.

Answer (score 1):

"fraga" in portuguese sounds "similar" to "花嘉" in cantonese, so my suggestion is:

### 花嘉樂

[fa1](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/faa1.Mp3)
[ga1](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/gaa1.Mp3)
[lok6](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/lok6.Mp3)

in which, "花" means "flower; blossom", a common surname. there's a famous ms 花 in history, 花木蘭 ([Mulan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hua_Mulan))

"嘉樂" could be interpreted as "admirable, amiable", it's from a quote in chapter 17 of doctrine of the mean (中庸 舜其大孝也)

> 嘉樂君子，憲憲令德！宜民宜人，受祿于天。保佑命之，自天申之！

> The admirable amiable prince,
> displayed conspicuously his excelling virtue,
> adjusting his people, and adjusting his officers.
> Therefore, he received from Heaven his emoluments of dignity
> It protected him, assisted him, decreed him the throne;
> sending from Heaven these favors, as it were repeatedly.

https://ctext.org/dictionary.pl?if=gb&id=10277

the original ode in the book of odes is 詩經 大雅 假樂:

> 假樂君子、顯顯令德。
> 宜民宜人、受祿于天。
> 保右命之、自天申之。

https://ctext.org/dictionary.pl?if=gb&id=16423

have fun :)